# Reference module from a module in separate Terraform projects

Tags: terraform

Is it possible with Terraform to have a directory structure like the following:

```
├── environments
│   └── production
│       ├── app1
│           ├── instances.tf
│       ├── app2
│       └── shared
│           ├── iam.tf
│           └── security_groups.tf
└── modules
    └── iam
    └── node
```

Where `environments/production/{app1, app2, shared}` all each have their own terraform state and each are independent of each other. However, from app1 and app2 I need to reference module output variables like security groups, IAM etc from shared.

So `environments/production/shared/iam.tf` looks like:

```
module "iam" {
    source = "../../../modules/iam"
    var1 = "foo"
    var2 = "bar"
    var3 = "car"
    var4 = "nar"
}
```

How then, from `app1`, or `app2` do I reference the instance of `iam` from `shared`?

`environments/production/app1/instances.tf`:

```
module "app1" {
    source = "../../../modules/node"
    iam_profile_id = { how do I reference the IAM module from shared here?
    // shared.module.iam.profile_id?
}
```

Comment: Nested modules are not recommended, so in app1 and app2, you should reference the modules you are going to use whether in modules or shared. Also, it is best practice not run all your automation at once, because it will be slow and difficult to manage. You should break it into independent components  that you can run in test,  dev, prod.

Comment: Additionally unsure why workspaces are not being utilized here, nor why the node module is being declared as `app1`, nor why an argument to it is being set to a module. Not to pile on here, but this structure and usage needs a reorg and refactor that will solve your problem along the way.

Comment: The problem is not nested modules, the problem is shared resources between instanications of modules in app1 and app2. Take for example a security group named `base` that should apply to all apps. How is that done when app1 and app2 are completely separate Terraform projects, with their own state file? I don't want to have Terraform try and create two `base` security groups, so I want to share that resource.

Comment: @Justin I normally run the base component in its own state and then use remote state to read it into another component. As an alternative you store the SecurityGroupIDs in the Ec2 parameter store and then read it from another component, which is my recommended way of doing it.

Comment: What @victorm says but don't use remote state, use the proper `aws_security_group` data source instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR can you explain, still not following how I reference a modules output variable from a completely separate Terraform directory with its own unique state file.